# How to get rid of "Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath" message?

Tags: cron, apache-spark

I am running an Apache Spark app as a cron job, but I keep getting emails with the following message

```
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath message
```

My cron entry is something like the following

```
...home/sparkJob.sh > /home/SaprkJobOperation-`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H`-cron.log
```

I understand that there are some log4j properties, and I have managed to log those to a file, but I am not able to suppress the message. I want to get emails only for stderr messages. Is there a way to suppress this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your spark version, this message may or may not appear. Additionally it was previously generated by the shell script `compute-classpath.sh`, so you could always just comment that line out from `compute-classpath.sh` (The line you are looking for is `echo "Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath" 1>&2`).

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I was hoping for some kind of setting, but this works. However there is another message that gets sent, also something that Spark spits out. "Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties". I did a grep for this, but couldn't find any references. Also, I want to point out that, all the logging messages are logged to a separate file, but this specific log message always shows up. Anyway to suppress this? II know this is a separate string, but it's around the same issue. Please let me know if you want me to open another question for this.

Comment: You could try grepping for the 1>&2 in the same file, but if it doesn't show up there probably another question would be best.